Merge PySpark table if condition is true
We try to update our table if a specific condition is fulfilled from the external data load. The code runs into several errors if we try this with our solution.
The output should update our spark table columns, where the external column has a an empty value in column recordmode
if initialLoad:
    df = pd.DataFrame(sdf, columns = ['RBR_Name', 'RECORDMODE', 'RBR_Kennzahl'])
    df['RBR_Kennzahl'] =  df['RBR_Kennzahl'].astype(float)#convert datatype of 'Kennzahl'
    df = df.drop(['RECORDMODE'], axis = 1)

append_records(df, dbWriteSchema, dbWriteTable)

update_last_recquest_table(dfRequests, dbWriteSchema, dbWriteTable, initialLoad)
else:

df = pd.DataFrame(sdf, columns = ['REQTSN','DATAPAKID','RECORD','RECORDMODE','RBR_NAME', 'RBR_Kennzahl'])
    df['RBR_Kennzahl'] =  df['RBR_Kennzahl'].astype(float)

dfAllReq = df['REQTSN'].unique()


sdfRequest = spark.read.table(dbWriteSchema+".tbl_rbr_requests")
    `sdfRequest = sdfRequest.where(col("TBLNAME") == dbWriteTable)
    sdfRequest.show()
    lastRequest = sdfRequest.agg(min("REQTSN")).head()
    lastRequest = sdfRequest.first()

 dfAllReq = pd.DataFrame(dfAllReq, columns=["REQTSN"])

df['R_Kennzahl'] =  df['R_Kennzahl'].astype(float)

#get list of all Requests in Change Log
dfAllReq = df['REQTSN'].unique()
#remove previously imported requests from list
sdfRequest = spark.read.table(dbWriteSchema+".tbl_rbr_requests")
sdfRequest = sdfRequest.where(col("TBLNAME") == dbWriteTable)
lastRequest = sdfRequest.agg(min("REQTSN")).head()
lastRequest = sdfRequest.first()
dfAllReq = pd.DataFrame(dfAllReq, columns=["REQTSN"])
dfNewReq = dfAllReq[ dfAllReq['REQTSN'] > lastRequest['REQTSN']]
if not dfNewReq.empty:
 #update sql table for each request and recordmode
    for request in dfNewReq['REQTSN']:
        print("Request =" + str(request))

 #insert new records (Recordmode = N)
        new_df = df[(df['REQTSN'] == request) & (df['RECORDMODE'] == "N")]
        new_df = new_df.drop(['REQTSN','DATAPAKID','RECORD','RECORDMODE'], axis = 1)
        append_records(new_df, dbWriteSchema, dbWriteTable)
#upadte changed records (Recordmode = "") 
        `update_df = df[(df['REQTSN'] == request) & (df['RECORDMODE'] == "")]
#update_records_merge(update_df, dbWriteSchema, dbWriteTable)
        if not update_df.empty:
            update_df = update_df.drop(['REQTSN','DATAPAKID','RECORD','RECORDMODE'], axis = 1)
            print(update_df)
            sdf = spark.createDataFrame(update_df)
            sdf.show()
 dbWritePath = "abfss://DatasphereConnect@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/" + dbWriteSchema + ".Lakehouse/Tables/" + dbWriteTable
matchCondition = "oldData.Name = newData.Name_n"
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, dbWritePath)
            deltaTable.alias('oldData') \
                .merge( \
                    sdf.alias('newData'), 'oldData.RBR_Name = newData.R_Name')\
                    .whenMatchedUpdate(set = {'oldData.RBR_Kennzahl': 'newData.R_Kennzahl' }) \
                .execute()

error:
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 26
     24 new_df = df[(df['REQTSN'] == request) & (df['RECORDMODE'] == "N")]
     25 new_df = new_df.drop(['REQTSN','DATAPAKID','RECORD','RECORDMODE'], axis = 1)
---> 26 append_records(new_df, dbWriteSchema, dbWriteTable)
     28 #upadte changed records (Recordmode = "") 
     29 update_df = df[(df['REQTSN'] == request) & (df['RECORDMODE'] == "")]

Cell In[10], line 40, in append_records(df, dbWriteSchema, dbTable)
     38 if not df.empty:
     39     sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
---> 40     sdf.write.mode("append").format("delta").saveAsTable(dbWriteSchema + "." + dbTable)

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1521, in DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1519 if format is not None:
   1520     self.format(format)
-> 1521 self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:175, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    171 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    172 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    173     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    174     # JVM exception message.
--> 175     raise converted from None
    176 else:
    177     raise

AnalysisException: A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table (Table ID: 989f009d-f6d6-4787-8c12-b0edaeafd503).
To enable schema migration using DataFrameWriter or DataStreamWriter, please set:
'.option("mergeSchema", "true")'.
For other operations, set the session configuration
spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled to "true". See the documentation
specific to the operation for details.

Table schema:
root
-- RBR_Name: string (nullable = true)
-- RBR_Kennzahl: double (nullable = true)


Data schema:
root
-- R_Name: string (nullable = true)
-- R_Kennzahl: double (nullable = true)

